# Add unsubscribe link on top of email with phpmailer?

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am trying to add a unsubscribe link on top of email like:
[![enter image description here][1]][1] this.

Here is the code i have written,

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->MessageID = $message_send_id;
// Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
$mail->isSendmail();
$mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->AddReplyTo(trim($_GET["in_rep_to"]));
$mail->addCustomHeader("List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@lovenlove.info?subject=delete>,<http://lovenlove.info/nishat/unsubscribe.php?email=".$value[0]["address"].">");
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom(trim($email_address), trim($value[0]["own_name"]));
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Hostname = trim($host_name);
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', $message_id);
$mail->addCustomHeader('References', $ref_id);

//mail addresscontains <*> this line to be edited
$mail->addAddress(trim($value[0]["address"]));
//Set the subject line
//code for subject here
$subject = $value[0]["message_to_send"]["subject"];
//code for body
$body = $value[0]["message_to_send"]["body"];

$mail->Subject = trim($subject);
$mail->Body    = trim($body);
//send the message, check for errors

if (!$mail->send()) echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
```

This sends header `List-Unsubscribe` with the email but link is not showing there.  I don't know this is the process or not.

I have `DKIM: PASS` and `SPF: NEUTRAL` record.

In mail header it shows, `List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@lovenlove.info?subject=delete>,<http://lovenlove.info/nishat/unsubscribe.php?email=heatherb6353@gmail.com>`. I can not find the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest you compare the list-unsubscribe headers of a working message with yours.

Comment: working header is different then mine. I can not solve that.

Comment: i have added those headers with the question.

Comment: You should just put them in the question, not on external sites. No need to include the rest of the message. Anyway, you're saying that just `List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:>` works?

Comment: I dont know how. but it works.

Comment: It is taking to there site also, though i don't see anything rather then `List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:>`

Comment: Sounds like the client might be changing/hiding it? List unsubscribe header values are intended to work alone - i.e. you don't need to add a message body - the mere existence of a message sent to that address is enough to complete the unsubscribe. For that reason they usually use VERP addressing to convey who the message is from. What happens if you remove the HTTP option from the header?

Comment: Not working. `List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@lovenlove.info?subject=delete>` and message going to spam directly.

Comment: And without the subject param? (You shouldn't need me to prompt you to do things like that!)

Comment: without subject param or header like `List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:>` i have tested also. nothing works.